# jQuery json data works fine from a file but not from php web service

Tags: jquery, json

I have a php web service returning json data. My problem is that when i call the json data from url returns nothing but when a call a local file with exactly the same data (copy from the url) works fine.

The json data i receive are for example

```
{"ResponseData":[{"Code":"91010001","Description":"ISADORA ","retailprice":"52.0000000000"},{"Code":"91010002","Description":"ISADORA ","retailprice":"52.0000000000"}]}
```

The script i use to get the json data is

```
     <script>$.getJSON("url",

    function(data){

                    var output = '';

      $.each(data.ResponseData, function(i,data){
         output += '<li><a href="#">' + data.Code + '</a></li>';
         if ( i == 50 ) return false;

      });
         $('#listview1').append(output).listview('refresh');
    });

 </script>
```

Finally, I used an ajax script just to display the json data but returns me error [object Object].

```
     <script>
 var obj 
  $.ajax({
url: 'url",
type: "GET",
dataType: 'json',
success: function( data ) {
  alert( "SUCCESS:  " + data );
},
error: function( data ) {
var obj = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
  alert( "ERROR:  " + data );
}
```

});

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Hope this helps: In application craft i used first a function obj2json to convert data to json and then json2obj to populate data.

**EDIT2:**
In IE9 i must click allow block content (for scripts or Active X) to display the data from the link. How i can do this to other browsers?

Comment: You really shouldn't pass a SQL statement in your query string.  You're opening yourself up to sql injection attacks big time.

Comment: Are there invalid characters in your URL?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what the problem is.  Where are you getting an error?  Are you just not seeing data being returned?  If you monitor your service call with Chrome tools or Firebug or Fiddler, what data do you see being returned?

Comment: Thank you David. i removed the link. I'll give a try with firebug and i'll tell you!!

Comment: Luke, when i use the link to firefox, chrome and internet explorer it returns me data.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "web service" as opposed to a "local file", it sounds like you might be sending a request to a different domain. Due to security restrictions, browsers don't allow that. Consider asking the remote service to support [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/) for cross-site communication, or routing the request through your own server (i.e., browser sends request to your server, your server sends request to remote server, your server gets response from remote server, your server responds with that same response).

Comment: I made a program for android before a month and an application craft app before some days and i used this link without a problem. I think i must get the data as string and convert them to json.

Comment: @phanisk: Android applications have different security restrictions than web browsers :/

Comment: With so many tries i am sure now that there are security restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use `JSON.parse(data)`

```
 $.getJSON("url",
function(data){
               data = JSON.parse(data);
               var output = '';
              $.each(data.ResponseData, function(i,data){
     output += '<li><a href="#">' + data.Code + '</a></li>';
     if ( i == 50 ) return false;

  });
     $('#listview1').append(output).listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: jQuery's `getJSON` function automatically parses `data` in advance; no need to re-parse it.

Comment: @Matchu yes sure getJSON is working fine but i like to use the JSON.parse so i can trace errors if i do have, so if it's json parse exception or ajax error.

Comment: Mkay, but then we'd need to not use `getJSON`, since `data` here is a JSON object, not a string, so `JSON.parse` will choke :/